# MongoTemplate find() with empty query takes a long time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongotemplate

My Mongo Collection has around 2000 documents. While using MongoTemplate find() method with empty query (i.e I need all the documents in the collection) and entity class, collection name it takes more than a minute to return the data in the form of a List. Could someone help me out to make the query return faster?? Below is the query I'm using.

```
Query query = new Query();
Class<MyObjects> CLASS_NAME = MyObjects.class;
String COLLECTION_NAME = "MyCollection";
List<MyObjects> myObjects = template.find(query, CLASS_NAME, COLLECTION_NAME);
```

Comment: I'm using Spring version 3.1.2.RELEASE (JFYI)

Comment: Try `template.findAll(MyObjects.class, COLLECTION_NAME)`

Answer (score -2):

```
@Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;        

public List<MyObjects> getMyObjects() {
        List<MyObjects> myObjects= null;
        try{
            myObjects=(List<MyObjects>)mongoTemplate.findAll(MyObjects.class);
if(myObjects.size()>0)
{
return myObjects;}
else{
return null;}
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myObjects;
    }
```

Comment: care to provide some kind of explanation?

Comment: @user3928299 How do u say that this improves the query response time?? Could you please explain?

Comment: @user3928299 i tried out your suggestion, results are still the same.. there is no increase in query response time.. I takes more than an minute..